# how to close ng-pick-datetime picker manually in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I am using ng-pick-datetime picker as a dialog mode. It is working fine but If I open it and moved to other route without closing it my application gets hang. So Please suggest me how to close the picker before moving to another path. I tried to get accessibility using ViewChild but it doesn't work.

```html
<button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == devices.name}" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt5">
                        <!-- [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : 'light'" -->
                        {{devices.name}}
                        <!-- To show datetime picker -->
                        <input [owlDateTime]="dt5" [(ngModel)]="selectedDateTime" class="hideInput" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"
                        (dateTimeInput)="getHistory(devices.imei_no,devices.remaining_days_to_expire,devices.name)">
                        <owl-date-time [pickerMode]="'dialog'" #dt5></owl-date-time>                         
                    </button>
```

```
@ViewChild('dt5') calendarView: ElementRef;

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.calendarView.nativeElement.visibility = 'hidden' //throwing error cannot set property of undefined element
}
```

Comment: You can use close event on ngDestroy part. Let me search for you.

Comment: Please tell me if there is any close event for ng-pick-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If you use *ngIf="" property on your picker, when you navigate to another route, the variable will be destroyed that means your picket will now shown anymore (Maybe there is another and more efficient way but this is the solution that i produce), please try this:

**on your template side,**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="showPicker"><button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == devices.name}" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt5">
                        <!-- [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : 'light'" -->
                        {{devices.name}}
                        <!-- To show datetime picker -->
                        <input [owlDateTime]="dt5" [(ngModel)]="selectedDateTime" class="hideInput" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"
                        (dateTimeInput)="getHistory(devices.imei_no,devices.remaining_days_to_expire,devices.name)">
                        <owl-date-time [pickerMode]="'dialog'" #dt5></owl-date-time>                         
                    </button></ng-template>
```

**on your component side,**

```
showPicker: boolean = true;
ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.showPicker = false;
}
```

If this not work, try to put ngIf to:
`<owl-date-time>` tag.

Comment: I want to close just picker dialog... not button. Picker still opened if I use this code that's why this is not working.

Comment: Did you try to put ngIf to <owl-date-time> tag ?

Comment: I've checked the properties of plugin, there is no event such as "close" or "hide": https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker#properties-for-owl-date-time